# MySQL select total row number in query with group by

Tags: mysql

I need to know total results of a query, I'm using COUNT()
the problem is that inside this query I have a GROUP BY

instead getting 5 as results I get 5 rows with total number of results for each row

```
SELECT  COUNT(c.id) AS tot
FROM    contributors AS c LEFT JOIN contributors_info AS ci 
        ON c.id = ci.idcontributor
WHERE   c.state = 'active'
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY c.id ASC
```

my query result is

```
|c.id|
| 1  |
| 2  |
| 1  |
| 1  |
| 1  |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below query.

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) as tot FROM(
    SELECT  c.id 
    FROM    CONTRIBUTORS AS c LEFT JOIN contributors_info AS ci 
        ON c.id = ci.idcontributor
    WHERE   c.state = 'active'
    GROUP BY c.id
    ORDER BY c.id ASC
) AS tmp
```

Comment: your query works, do you now if is faster than using SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS?